# updating VBA Custom Functions

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function(which returns the last row number of any selected column)

```
Function LastrowCC(SelectedRange As Range)
Dim SelectedColumnNum As Long
SelectedColumnNum = SelectedRange.Column
LastrowCC = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, SelectedColumnNum).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

the problem is that when the last row of the selected column is deleted the function does not update automatically

can we make VBA custom functions update automatically when inputs change?

Comment: you would have to call it from an event procedure. But still this is unclear, a function can't update itself if its not called from some other place so I am not actually sure what you mean here

Comment: I mean what you exactly clarified, I want the custom function to update automatically just like the built in functions of excel.

Comment: are you using it on a spreadsheet?

Comment: it depends on how you call it. If you cal it like this: `=LastrowCC(A1:A2)` - it updates only if you change any cell from `A1:A2`. If you call it like this: `=LastrowCC(A:A)` - it updates whenever you change any cell in `A:A`. Also you can add `Application.Volatile True` in the beggining of function - in that case it doesn't matter what `SelectedRange As Range` is. It'd be updated every time _any_ cell on worksheet changed

Comment: are you sure you have not switched Calculation to manual? Try `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and it should update automatically

Comment: @mehow Yes I am using it on a spreadSheet

Comment: @simoco really thank you these are valuable tips

Answer (score 3):

At risk of repeating the helpful comments and answers already posted, let me point out that there are several issues involved in your question, summed up nicely in the MSDN article "[Excel Recalculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891%28v=office.15%29.aspx)."

A more specific question, including the Excel version and the way calculation is handled on your worksheet, may help narrow things down a bit.

Let me sum up some things you may want to check out, all listed in the article above:

- There are several ways a recalculation is triggered, including functions. Studying the way this happens may shed some insight. According to the article, "The calculation of worksheets in Excel can be viewed as a three-stage process:

  1. Construction of a dependency tree,
  2. Construction of a calculation chain,
  3. Recalculation of cells."
- Volatile functions are an option, but because of resource consumption should be used sparingly and wisely.
- You may also explore [Range.Dirty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838797%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [Range.Calculate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834613%28v=office.15%29.aspx) methods, which starting in Excel 2002 (that's farther back in the past than some of us realize!) allows "forced recalculation," to again quote the article above.

These are a few options and things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Make it **Volatile** :

```
Function LastrowCC(SelectedRange As Range) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim SelectedColumnNum As Long
    SelectedColumnNum = SelectedRange.Column
    LastrowCC = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, SelectedColumnNum).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: It means the function gets recalculated whenever the worksheet gets recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

The key to making a function work within Excel's calculation tree and not be volatile is to include everything you need in the arguments to the function. That is, don't reference any ranges that are not included in the arguments to the function.

In your example, you can send it any single cell and it will return the last row of that same column. But you're looking outside of that single cell so Excel doesn't know that the whole column should be in the calculation tree.

In this rewrite, the function only accepts single, whole column arguments. If you send it less than a whole column, it returns an error. If you send it more than one column, it returns an error. But since the whole column is in the argument, any changes in the column trigger a recalc.

```
Public Function LastRowCc(ByVal SelectedRange As Range)

    If SelectedRange.Address = SelectedRange.EntireColumn.Address And SelectedRange.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        LastRowCc = SelectedRange.Find("*", SelectedRange.Cells(1), , , , xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        LastRowCc = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If

End Function
```